# Deleting a user and the user profile

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm new into SQL and stored procedures, and need some help with the stored procedure below. I have to tables that are connected to each other: "User" and "Profile".

When deleting a user the user profile should also be deleted, and that's what the SP below does. However, when executing the SP all the UserIDs in the table User shows up (of course because of "SELECT UserID), and this is something I don't want.

So, I guess my question is how to write the Sp so that it works without using SELECT?

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteUser
@UserID int
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        SELECT u.UserID 
        FROM [User] AS u INNER JOIN Profile AS p
             ON u.UserID = p.UserID;

        DELETE FROM Profile
        WHERE UserID = @UserID;

        DELETE FROM [User]
        WHERE UserID = @UserID;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('Borttagningen gick inte att genomföra!',16,1)
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: Just remove the `SELECT` - it does nothing in regards to the deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Profile.UserID` should be a foreign key indicating a one-to-one relationship with the `User` table, with `ON DELETE CASCADE` specified.  Then you delete the record from the `User` table, and the associated record in the `Profile` table will automatically be removed.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is redundant.  Remove it:

```
    SELECT u.UserID 
    FROM [User] AS u INNER JOIN Profile AS p
         ON u.UserID = p.UserID;
```

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT is completely unnecessary and was probably added by someone as a test. You shoud also add `SET NOCOUNT ON` right after your `AS BEGIN` to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the SELECT statement. It's not actually adding anything to your query.